# How to stop other classes from changing colour when changing an "HTML" tag background colour

Tags: html, css, reactjs, background-image

Hello I am trying to change the background of my page using the following code in a file called
***Survey.module.css***:

```
html  {
    background-image: linear-gradient( 94.3deg,  rgba(26,33,64,1) 10.9%, rgba(81,84,115,1) 87.1% );
  }
```

I've imported the CSS into my react component using the following import statement: ***import style from './Survey.js'***

The code in ***Survey.js is below***

```
  import React from 'react'
import { Container, Col, Row } from 'react-bootstrap'
import style from './Survey.module.css'

function Survey() {
  return (
  <html>
  <div>
    <h1 className="display-5 text-center mt-5 text-white">Tell us about yourself</h1>
    <div className={`${style.container} d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center`}>
      <div className='row justify-content-md-center'>
        <div className='col col-lg-5 shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded'>
          <img src='https://static.toiimg.com/photo/msid-77430626/77430626.jpg?228049' className='rounded img-fluid'></img>
        </div>
        <div className='col col-lg-5 shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded'>
          <h1></h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </html>
  )
}

export default Survey
```

My issue is that when I change the background in CSS with the above code, the background of other pages in my project also change. All those pages import their CSS files using ***.module.css
I tried to use CSS modules to avoid this problem but I am still encountering it. Any advice?

Comment: `<html style="background-image: linear-gradient(...)">...</html>`

Answer (score 0):

Give your html class so your css doesn't affect to other page.

```css
html.survey  {
    background-image: linear-gradient( 94.3deg,  rgba(26,33,64,1) 10.9%, rgba(81,84,115,1) 87.1% );
}
```

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Container, Col, Row } from 'react-bootstrap'
import style from './Survey.module.css'

function Survey() {
  return (
  <html className="survey">
  <div>
    <h1 className="display-5 text-center mt-5 text-white">Tell us about yourself</h1>
    <div className={`${style.container} d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center`}>
      <div className='row justify-content-md-center'>
        <div className='col col-lg-5 shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded'>
          <img src='https://static.toiimg.com/photo/msid-77430626/77430626.jpg?228049' className='rounded img-fluid'></img>
        </div>
        <div className='col col-lg-5 shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded'>
          <h1></h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </html>
  )
}

export default Survey
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a `div` with a your preferred `className` that wraps the rest of the content and you can add your `css` styling like `background-image` to it. I don't get logic behind setting a `background-image` on the entire `html` document.

```
<div className={styles.surveyContainer}>
    <div className={styles.content}>
        ...rest of the content
    </div>
</div>
```